# Where can I find photon absorption cross-sections for various isotopes?

Tags: photons, nuclear-physics, scattering-cross-section, absorption, data

I am looking for absorption cross-sections for photons. Usually, I am dealing with neutron absorption where I utilize https://www.nndc.bnl.gov/endf/ for my data. This is a really handy website that provides neutron capture/fission/etc cross-sections. Is there a similar website for photon cross-sections? If so, let me know!

Comment: If you mean 'gamma' for the more generic 'photon', then ENDF does just fine - use 'g' for the reaction instead of 'n'

Answer (score 0):

You can choose  here  ,

NIST  Xcom   : https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/Xcom/Text/intro.html

or , older   https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/NSRDS/nbsnsrds29.pdf